# I want to populate my form elements with data i fetch from my database in another php file using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to populate my form elements with a row fetched from a database. I am trying to use ajax to send the id of the row i want to fetch when a button is clicked.

I am trying to use ajax. I have successfully retrieved the row i want in the php file but cant send the data back to the requesting page.

My table has edit and delete buttons for each row.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr style="margin:10px;">';
    echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['uname']."<td>";
    echo '<td><button class="btn btn-warning" onClick="editBtnClicked('.$row['id'].')">Edit</button><td>';
    echo '<td><button class="btn btn-danger" onClick="deleteBtnClicked('.$row['id'].')">Delete</button><td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

And my script looks like this:

```
function editBtnClicked(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'edit.php',
        data: { edit_id: id },
        success: function (data) {
            // ...
        }
    })
}
```

And my `edit.php` file:

```
$id= $_POST['edit_id'];

$stmt= "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=".$id;

$result= $conn->query($stmt);

$rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

I want to send `$rows['name']` and `$rows['body']` to the page that contains the table and populate a form that has two text areas with it.

Comment: You should use JSON as the data transport format: `echo json_encode($row);`

Comment: I was in the middle of typing that @misorude. I was gonna say he should use json_encode() in the `edit.php` file, and in his success function, pass the data to a variable

Comment: how can i take the strings i specifically want from the json

Comment: In your success handler, log `data` to the browser console, and inspect it - then you see what you are dealing with. (And if you then still don’t know how to proceed from there - then you should rather be working through some beginner’s tutorials right now, because explaining the absolute basics is not what SO should be [ab]used for.)

Comment: Take a look here at this [tutorial](https://jonsuh.com/blog/convert-loop-through-json-php-javascript-arrays-objects/). It should guide you if you follow it comprehensively.

Comment: @A6du2 i've answered on this question. If you find it helpful, please accept it. It will help me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of your `edit.php` file, add this line

```
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Modify your function like this:
(I am assuming that your name and body textareas have ids `nameTextArea` and `bodyTextArea` respectively.)

```
function editBtnClicked(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'edit.php',
        data: { edit_id: id },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#nameTextArea').val(data.name);
            $('#bodyTextArea').val(data.body);
        }
    })
}
```